# $\epsilon-\delta$ Verification

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Define $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ for all $x\ge 0$. Verify the $\epsilon-\delta$ criterion for continuity at $x=4$. *Hint:* first show that for $x\ge 0$ and $x_0> 0$, $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}|\le|x-x_0|/\sqrt{x_0}$.

---

I started by trying to show that for $x\ge 0$ and $x_0> 0$, $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}|\le|x-x_0|/\sqrt{x_0}$, but I haven't been able to get anywhere. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use that $\sqrt x >0$ and $$\sqrt x-\sqrt {x_0}=\frac{x-x_0}{\sqrt x+\sqrt {x_0}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $x-x_0=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0})$, then
$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}|=\dfrac{|x-x_0|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}}\leq\dfrac{|x-x_0|}{\sqrt{x_0}}$$